# c# mongodb store last N chat messages

Tags: c#, mongodb, signalr, chat

Im in the phase of designing (haven't wrote code yet!) a scalable chat application using signalR.

I would like to limit a chat room document (in mongodb) to store the last 100 messages.

In order to do that I thought about somehow storing a circular array.
I thought about maintaining a thread safe index, assuming Index, so 0 <= Index < 100, And so, updating the array in the database in the given index.

Now, I have 2 dilemas:

1st, Either maintain this chat in some dedicated text file or in mongodb.

2nd, assuming I would like to scaleout, maintaining this index up to date in several slave servers wouldn't be effective.

When I relate to performance and efficiency here, I would like to spend most of the resources and time when a user joins the chat and not when he already uses it.

Any ideas or suggestions?

(I dont think its an open question for debate because I asked 2 specific questions and how they can be solved.)

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need to maintain a db on one specific server for this purpose, using SELECT TOP 100 when a user logs on, and then conducting daily (or weekly) maintenance to DELETE ROWNUM>100 for each user.

As far as resources, if you want to have this feature, you need to dedicate the resources. DB is the only way to go assuming users will log in from different devices. Local TXT files would be device-specific.